# if statement on char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, syntax, char

i have this syntax.
i have a problem with the second function (validateGuess)
this function should chek the char that the user introduce to the program.
i made a function that ask from the user again a letter if is not a letter between 0-9 (on main).
but if put a letter, the program ask from the user write it again.
but if i put a number like 22, the program doesnt ask from the user it again because i dont know how to limit the imput to 1 digit.
it is important to say that my teacher ask from us made a char array and not int array.
and i need that the if statement check it only in the function. and if it return 1 is legal number, if is return 0 is ilegal and should write again.

here is the syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 5
void GenerateCode(char code[SIZE]);
int validateGuess(char guess[]);

void main ()
{
    int i;
    char code[SIZE]={0};
    char input[SIZE]={0};
    GenerateCode(code);
    printf("Write your guess please\n");
    for(i=0;i<SIZE-1;i++)
    {
    scanf("%s",&input[i]);
    if(validateGuess(&input[i])==0)
        {
            printf("Wrong input, put a number between 0 to 9\n");
            i--;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
}

void GenerateCode(char code[SIZE])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        code[i]=rand()%10;
    }
}

int validateGuess(char guess[])
{
    int validateGuess=0;
    if((guess[0]>=49) && (guess[0]<=57))
        validateGuess=1;

    return validateGuess;
}
```

Comment: is this C or C++? Can you add that tag as well?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&input[i]);` doesn't do what you think it does. Read the documentation of `scanf()`, then **stop using it.** Use sane and actually useful functions, such as `getchar()` or `fgets()` instead.

Comment: `if((guess[0]>='0') && (guess[0]<='9') && guess[1] == '\0')`, and there is a problem with this scanf as H2CO3 saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can not limit the input from user, at least not in this way. But you can read a line from your stream (stdin I guess) using something like the getline function and check for its length using strlen. If the input has not the right size, ask again for input, until you get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I will not provide a complete solution, but there are a couple of errors in your code that I'd like to point out so you can solve this problem step by step:

- The array initialization `char code[SIZE]={0};` is redundant because a declaration `char code[SIZE];` will declare an array of `SIZE` elements - all set to `0` anyway.
- Calling `scanf("%s", &input[i]);` tells `scanf` to read a string of characters and put that string into a `char` array position. You want to read a single `char` here, representing a single digit, so use `%c` instead of `%s`. This will truncate all input , provided by the user, except the first character. So input `33` will store `3`, input `123` will store `1` and so on.
- This test `if(validateGuess(&input[i])==0)` passes the *address* of `input[i]` to `validateGuess`, not the *contents* of `input[i]`. To pass the contents you don't use unary `&` operator.
- Change the signature of `validateGuess()` to `validateGuess(char guess)` and change its body to treat `guess` as single character representing a digit. Since you only expect a digit from `0` to `9`, you can't also have a guess equal to `49` or `57` or any other value of two or more digits. That logic should be changed in your program.

To get the numerical value of a character representing a single digit you could use the following function:

```
int num(char c) {
    return c - '0';
}
```

A comparison of a character against an integer value would then look like:

```
if (num(c) == 2) {
    /* c is the digit 2 */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi,
if i change SIZE-1 to SIZE is compilation error because i made an array of size 5 to introduce 4 chars (the last place is for \0) so i introduce until char number of 4 that is until place 0,1,2, -- 3 --
the place 4 is \0)

and if i delete the & is compilation error, how i compare the content?

Comment: @user3077648 Okay, see update. I had some errors in my statements.

Comment: It is wrong that here in block scope _a declaration `char code[SIZE];` will declare an array of `SIZE` elements - all set to `0` anyway._ C Standard: **If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.**